# Bias in survey questions based on either positive or negative wording

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias, survey, consumer-psychology

I have this impression that if you ask respondents in a survey, questions such as "do you like the item X/ person X" or "which one of the two variations do you like more", or "what in particular would you like about the item X/ person X", etc, you would get a lot of bias and rationalizations. That is, "say vs think vs do" would be extremely disparate.

At the same time, I would expect negative questions such as "is there something you dislike about the item X" or "could you list top three shortcomings of the item X/ person X", etc, to render quite objective responses; I would expect strong consistency between what respondents would say compared to what they actually think or feel and then compared to what they would actually do.

(Of course, I exclude some extreme cases of social desirability.)

Given that I am speaking about my subjective impressions, based on my personal limited observations, I would like to ask, is there such a pattern indeed and if so, how could it be possibly explained?

Comment: am i right in assuming, that you ask, whether a positive framing vs. a negative framing of questions will result in a smaller gab between "doing" vs. "attitude"?

Comment: @ bucky - I am not sure what you mean by  "attitude". Let me resort to an example to what I mean: dating survey among females, question variation a) "What do you like in men?" - I'd expect answers such as "intelligence, sense of humour, chivalry"; question variation b) "What do you dislike in men" - I'd expect answers such as "bad hygiene, insecurity, immaturity" and I'd expect the latter to be closer to what the females really think and how they really behave in a dating situation as opposed to what they say, and opposed to how they think they behave in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your examples can be explained with the Anchoring bias (aslo know as focalism).

> Anchoring or focalism is a cognitive bias that describes the common
>   human tendency to rely too heavily on the first piece of information
>   offered (the "anchor") when making decisions. During decision making,
>   anchoring occurs when individuals use an initial piece of information
>   to make subsequent judgments. Once an anchor is set, other judgments
>   are made by adjusting away from that anchor, and **there is a bias
>   toward interpreting other information around the anchor**.

A theory that explains anchoring is [selective accessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring#Selective_accessibility).

> selective accessibility proposes that when given an anchor, a judge
>   (i.e. a person making some judgment) will evaluate the hypothesis that
>   the anchor is a suitable answer. Assuming it is not, the judge moves
>   on to another guess, but not before accessing all the relevant
>   attributes of the anchor itself. Then, when evaluating the new answer,
>   the judge looks for ways in which it is similar to the anchor,
>   resulting in the anchoring effect.

The Anchoring is a type of priming. The following extract is from [Brain Bugs](https://books.google.com.cy/books?id=eAKIcDmhBuEC&dq=brain%20bugs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLyJqG3NnYAhXL16QKHT3jAK4Q6AEIJTAA) by Dean Buonomano :

[image]

Below is the definition of [priming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)) :

> Priming is a technique whereby exposure to one stimulus influences a
>   response to a subsequent stimulus, without conscious guidance or
>   intention. For example, the word NURSE is recognized more quickly
>   following the word DOCTOR than following the word BREAD. Priming can
>   be perceptual, semantic, or conceptual.